# How two use two markdown themes with same blade names?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a second path in the `mail` config for [markdown mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#markdown-mailables):

```
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        resource_path('views/vendor/newsletter'),
    ],
],
```

Every new component in `views/vendor/newsletter` can be accessed in a mail blade like this:

```
@component('mail::message-newsletter')
```

However, I can't access `views/vendor/newsletter/message.php` because its already in `views/vendor/mail/message.php`.

I would like to use same blade names `button`, `footer`, `header`, `layout`, `message` etc. for my newsletter template.

I tried to add a `newsletter` alias like this:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(resource_path('views/vendor/newsletter'), 'newsletter');
```

so that I could access the `message` like this:

```
@component('newsletter::message')
```

Unfortunately, this returns the following error:

> View [message] not found.

I could fix it by doing

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(resource_path('views/vendor/newsletter/html'), 'newsletter');
```

but then the markdown files in `resource_path('views/vendor/newsletter/markdown'` would not be rendered.

I thought it would work, because the newsletter path is set in the config. Isn't `mail` also just pointing to `resource_path('views/vendor/mail')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mail` namespace

```
@('mail::
```

is overwritten, depending on if `render` for HTML is called or `renderText` for text is called. This is hardcoded in `Illuminate\Mail\Markdown` so you can't use `@('newsletter::` for HTML and raw.

What you could get the `Markdown` class from ServiceContainer and change the compontes path:

```
$markdown = \Illuminate\Container\Container::getInstance()->make(\Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::class);
$markdown->loadComponentsFrom([
    resource_path('views/vendor/newsletter'), ]);
```

this would use `message`, `footer`, `header` etc. only from newsletter folder.